# Passing UTF8 encoded data from big endian system to little endian system and vice-versa

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, binary, endianness

I have created a UTF-8 encoded file using Java API, now I have to transfer this file to some other system where some application will read it and process it.

Now, I have used UTF-8 encoding because I have [read](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) that it doesn't depend upon endianness of the processor, but I am having doubt that suppose I created the file using Java API from a big endian system/processor so for my all multi-byte characters, MSB will be first; now I pass this UTF8 encoded file to a system which is little endian, now the application over there will try to read it using UTF8 but since processor is little endian so it will consider first byte to be a LSB instead of MSB.

So, wouldn't this cause problem?

Wouldn't `11001100 10001000` (decimal 52360) will be considered/read as `10001000 11001100` (decimal 35020) because of endianness issue?

Comment: `but I am having doubt` what makes you think they lie to you? Read `Q: Is the UTF-8 encoding scheme the same irrespective of whether the underlying processor is little endian or big endian?` in their FAQ.

Comment: @tkausl Well, lets say I want to understand how, what they are saying, is true. I have read that point in FAQ, it is a statement and I have understood it, now foe me it is about "how".

Comment: The UTF-8 specification **defines** how a stream of bytes that represent must look. Code running on any processor, whether it's big or little endian, must make sure it interprets the bytes correctly. It looks like you're thinking about this backwards. It's the UTF-8 standard that specifies what the sequence of bytes is, not the processor.

Comment: @Jesper I think you answer has helped me but I think if you could elaborate it and put it as answer then it will not only help me (and other future visitors) get more understanding but I could also accept that as answer.

Comment: If there is a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the UTF-8 sequence then the program reading the bytes can determine whether it's litte-endian or big-endian and parse it appropriately.